# Create array of objects based off the same property names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have form inputs that are generated based off an XML file.

We keep a reference of nested elements in the XML file via `data-*` attributes which can later be used to build an object. For example:

```
<parent>
 <child>
  <grandchild1>first</grandchild1>
  <grandchild2>second</grandchild2>
 </child>
</parent>
```

Becomes

`<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild1" value="first"/> 
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild2" value="second"/>`

When we submit the form, I create an object (with nested objects) based off of their `data-nest` attribute. The above would become

```
parent:{
 child:{
  grandchild1: first,
  grandchild2: second
  }
}
```

The issue that I am running into is where multiple of the same tag are found in the XML file, e.g.

```
<child>
 <grandchild>first</grandchild>
 <grandchildFriend>firstFriend</grandchildFriend>
</child>
<child>
 <grandchild>second</grandchild>
 <grandchildFriend>secondFriend</grandchildFriend>
</child>
```

When I create my object, I would like it so that if multiple occurrences of the same `data-nest` value are found, they are nested inside of an array in order to maintain the different values.

With the current setup, the second occurrence of the tag will understandably overwrite the first.

This is the final object structure I desire:

```
parent:{
 child:[
  {
   grandchild: first,
   grandchildFriend: firstFriend
  }, 
  {
   grandchild: second,
   grandchildFriend: secondFriend
  }
  ]
 }
```

**TL;DR**

I'd like to change an object to an array of nested objects if they have the same `data-*` attribute

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ado7eLL9/23/) of how the current code works to help give a better understanding.

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to have two different kind of result, one more "concise" and the second as you believed :)

Comment: I think there's a flaw in your labeling strategy - if you had two `parent.child.grandChild` keys, there's no way to tell whether this should be `{ parent: { child: { grandChild: ['value1', 'value2'] } } }` (`grandChild` is array) or whether it should be `{ parent: { child: [ { grandChild: 'value1' }, { grandChild: 'value2' }] } } }` (`child` is array). Perhaps it would be better to include index numbers when converting the XML structure into `data-nest` values (and only include them if there are siblings with the same name). That way the structure is clear and it's clear when you need an array

Comment: @JLRishe, I did try indexing as you suggested - the problem I run into is that when creating the JSON object there are numbers in the tag names (`parent.child.grandchild1` where it should be `parent.child.grandchild`) inherently making the indexed properties void. As for determining where the array should sit (in my example it should be `child `as the array, with `grandchild` maintaining an object structure) my idea was to determine multiple occurrences of the same property name, and convert the parent to an array so each `grandchild` is pushed to the array rather than replacing the previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by attacking with a different approach.

We set the element we want as the array with `[]` added to the end of its `data-nest` attribute - we can then use this as the baseline for what we want converted.

If anyone is curious, here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ado7eLL9/30/)

Answer (score 0):

replacing `currentObj[lastKey] = value;` with this:

```
if(typeof currentObj[lastKey] === 'undefined') {
    currentObj[lastKey] = value;
} else  {
    if(typeof currentObj[lastKey] !== 'array')
            currentObj[lastKey] = [currentObj[lastKey]];
    currentObj[lastKey].push(value);
}
```

the code will do the following: if currentObj[lastKey] is not set, you will create an element as always, otherwise, if it is already set and is a string the code will convert it into an array and then push into the arrays the subsequent (as many as you want) elements
and the final result will be something similar to:

```
parent:{
...
 grandchild:[
   "first", "second"
  ]
...
 }
```

**Edit**
in order to have a result in the format that you have requested, you need to do some more edit, like following:

```
var json = {};

config = {
  set: function(keyValueString) {

    var pair = keyValueString.split('=');

    // left of the = is the key path
    var keyPath = pair[0];

    // right of the = is the value to set
    var value = pair[1];

    // split keyPath into an array of keys
    var keys = keyPath.split('.');
    var key;

    var currentObj = json;

    // loop through all keys in the key path, except the last one.
    // this creates the object structure implied by the key path.
    // we want to do something different on the last iteration.
    for (var i=0; i < keys.length-1; i++) {

      // Get the current key we are looping
      key = keys[i];
      // if the requested level on the current object doesn't exist,
      // make a blank object.
      if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'undefined') {
        currentObj[key] = i === keys.length-2 ? []: {};
      }

      currentObj = currentObj[key];
    }

    // our loop doesn't handle the last key, because that's when we
    // want to set the actual value.
    var lastKey = keys[keys.length-1]

    // set the property of the deepest object to the value.
    var child = {};
    child[lastKey] = value;
    currentObj.push(child);
  }
};

// iterate through all of our inputs, and nest them based off their data-* attribute
$('input').each(function(){
    // set nest = value setup, e.g. parent.child.grandchild = first
  // we then break this 
    var key = $(this).attr('data-nest') + '=' + $(this).val();
  config.set(key);
});

// as a bonus - this is how I went about breaking multiple values within a single input into an array
function traverseObject(object){
  // iterate through the object
  for (var i in object){


    // if the next key exists, run again
    if(object[i] !== null && typeof(object[i])=="object"){
      traverseObject(object[i]);
    } else {
    var value = [object[i]];
     // if the value contains a comma
    if(value.toString().indexOf(',') > -1){
      // set the *nested* key to the 
      // value as an array by splitting at the commas
      object[i] =value.toString().split(',').filter(function(el){
        // remove the extra entry after splitting
        return el.length != 0;
      });
    }
    }
  }
}

traverseObject(json);

$('#test').on('click', function(){
    console.log(json)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/ado7eLL9/19/

by updating the set method of config like this

```
if (typeof currentObj[lastKey] === 'undefined') {
   currentObj[lastKey] = value;
} else if(!Array.isArray(currentObj[lastKey])) {
  currentObj[lastKey] = [currentObj[lastKey], value];    
} else if(Array.isArray(currentObj[key])){
  currentObj[lastKey].push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `config.set()` as follows:

```js
var json = {};

config = {
  set: function(keyValueString) {

    var pair = keyValueString.split('=');

    // left of the = is the key path
    var keyPath = pair[0];

    // right of the = is the value to set
    var value = pair[1];

    // split keyPath into an array of keys
    var keys = keyPath.split('.');
    var key;

    var currentObj = json;

    // loop through all keys in the key path, except the last one.
    // this creates the object structure implied by the key path.
    // we want to do something different on the last iteration.
    for (var i=0; i < keys.length-1; i++) {

      // Get the current key we are looping
      key = keys[i];
      // if the requested level on the current object doesn't exist,
      // make a blank object.
      if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'undefined') {
        currentObj[key] = {};
      }

      currentObj = currentObj[key];
    }

    // our loop doesn't handle the last key, because that's when we
    // want to set the actual value.
    var lastKey = keys[keys.length-1]

    
    if (typeof currentObj[lastKey] === 'undefined') {
      // set string if nothing exists
       currentObj[lastKey] = value;
       
    } else if(!Array.isArray(currentObj[lastKey])) {
      // if exists and is not an array, 
      // create an array with two items
      // previously stored value (string) with lastKey key
      // current value 
      var previous = { [lastKey]: currentObj[lastKey] };
      var current  = { [lastKey]: value };
      currentObj[lastKey] = [previous, current];  
      
    } else if(Array.isArray(currentObj[key])){
      // if exists and is an array
      // push the new object to it
      var current = { [lastKey]: value }
      currentObj[lastKey].push(current);
      
    }
  }
};

// iterate through all of our inputs, and nest them based off their data-* attribute
$('input').each(function(){
 // set nest = value setup, e.g. parent.child.grandchild = first
  // we then break this 
 var key = $(this).attr('data-nest') + '=' + $(this).val();
  config.set(key);
});

// as a bonus - this is how I went about breaking multiple values within a single input into an array
function traverseObject(object){
  // iterate through the object
  for (var i in object){
    var value = [object[i]];
    
    // EDIT: continue only if value is not an array
    if(!Array.isArray(object[i])) {
      // if the value contains a comma
      if(value.toString().indexOf(',') > -1){
        // set the *nested* key to the 
        // value as an array by splitting at the commas
        object[i] = value.toString().split(',').filter(function(el){
          // remove the extra entry after splitting
          return el.length != 0;
        });
      }
      // if the next key exists, run again
      if(object[i] !== null && typeof(object[i])=="object"){
        traverseObject(object[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

traverseObject(json);

$('#test').on('click', function(){
 console.log(json)
});
```

```css
#test{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
input{
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Below are unique tags (working fine)</label>
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild1" value="gchild1-first"/>
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild2" value="gchild2-second"/>

<label>Below is multiple occurances of the same tag (find a way to break these into an array of objects)</label>
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild" value="gchild-first"/>
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.grandchild" value="gchild-second"/>

<label>Single array example</label>
<input type="text" data-nest="parent.child.array" value="this,is,an,array"/>

<div id="test">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close - the only couple of issues are that it is specific to two properties, and in your example, `grandchild` becomes nested objects inside a `grandchild` array - rather than it's parent.

Comment: so, what you want is: `{ parent: { child: { grandchild1: 'gchild1-first', granchild2: 'g-child2-second' }, grandchild: [{ granchild: 'gchild-first' }, { granchild: 'gchild-second'}] }` - with `child` and `grandchild` properties at the same depth? Could you update your question with whole object you expect to produce?

Comment: `grandchild1` and `grandchild2` were just used as an example to begin with, we can ignore these for now. What I am aiming for is, that if a property name appears multiple times (say for example we have four `grandchild`s) we can make the object it is nested inside of (in this case `child`) an array, and populate that array with the `grandchild` objects. e.g. `{ parent: { child: [ { grandchild: 'gchild-first' }, { grandchild: 'gchild-second' }, ... ] } }`. The goal of this is to be able to pass multiple property values that have the exact same name. This is how I imagine I would achieve that.